# about string format wrong

Tags: android

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" 
     attribute?
    - error: Unexpected end tag string

when i use string like:You have %d appointment(s)\n..and %d task(s). my sdk2.2 .i donot know why appear this mistakes.

Comment: Please provide some code, where you are getting this error.

Comment: only i string appear wrong,my string :You have %d appointment(s)\n..and %d task(s)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it should be
You have %1$d appointment(s)\n..and %2$d task(s)

Check this out
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/3457068e42b4c8be